# PHP warning : Module 'mcrypt' already loaded

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.10

When I run  a command with PHP, it shows me an error. E.g when I run `php -v` to see my PHP-version it shows me an error then the informations about PHP:

> Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

```
zied@ubuntu:~$ php -v

PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP 5.4.25-1+sury.org~quantal+2 (cli) (built: Feb 12 2014 11:11:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your `php.ini` contains two or more of these lines:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Remove all except one.

`php.ini` usually lives in `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php5/php.ini`. Sometimes additional .ini files are included, you can see all of them with:

```
$ php -i | grep .ini\$
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php.ini
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i deleted the line **extension=mcrypt.so ** in **/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini** and the error is disappeared now  thnx

Comment: This happened to me when I upgraded from PHP 5.6.15 to PHP 7.0 on my Debian DigitalOcean droplet. I've had no problems developing with this error showing; however, it is still very annoying when running stuff in the shell. Your answer is very much appreciated :).

Comment: I also faced this issue when I upgraded from PHP 5.5.9 to PHP 7.0 on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. And I found solution from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-7-0-php-warning-module-mcrypt-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0  so I just remove mcrypt module :  sudo apt-get remove php7.0-mcrypt as PHP7.0 from ondrej is already compiled with mcrypt.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this happens with `php-fpm`, and the funny thing is, console `php` doesn't complans about this using the same set of .ini-files in the same time, proving that `mcrypt` in fact isn't referenced twice.

As it turns out, `php-fpm` has a default set of modules built-in that it's trying to load, at least on Linux (since that isn't reproducible on FreeBSD). `mcrypt` is in this list, so when a user has an additional .ini-file in it's `/etc/php.d` directory, `mcrypt` seems to be loaded twice.

A harsh workaround for this is to add the `-n` switch to the php-fpm on the start, copy `pnp.ini` to a `php-fpm.ini`, include all of your modules into the resulting `php-fpm.ini` ***except mcrypt*** and add an additional switch pointing at the correct ini-file, so the whole addition looks like: `-n -c /etc/php-fpm.ini`.

This way running `php-fpm` won't complain.

I'm writing this here, because this is most referenced post in search engines about `mcrypt` issue. I realize the source question was about console php.

**Update:** I was using this workaround, but it is nasty. Some time ago I have figured out exactly why did this happen. I'll spend some more words to describe this, but this can be boring, since this will describe a certain type of failure. So, in my case this issue was caused by the fact, that I was using a custom php build, made by myself, and occasionally I've added the *mcrypt* to the list of builtin *static* modules. And ***then*** I added it again as a built module, so it **was loaded twice**. This happens with a custom build when *mcrypt* is referenced in the list of modules for the configure script, and isn't listed as *shared* (this part of the spec can be easily found, since `%configure \` is mentioned only once in the spec). In my case the solution was to remove the *mcrypt* entirely from the configure part, and add it to the `build-cgi` and `build-ztscli` stages. One could ask *" What about the fpm stage ?"* - and it's a good question, but, it turns out, *fpm* sapi itself is built with a minimum of modules and uses generic *shared* ones.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was due to building PHP from source with `./configure --with-mcrypt` option. It seems that if PHP is built with the `--with-mcrypt` flag, then there is no need to specify `extension=mcrypt.so` in `php.ini`. Doing so causes the warning mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Open php.ini and find `extension=mcrypt.so`

Comment it by adding a semicolon before the name extension `;extension=mcrypt.so`