# PHP pcntl module install

Tags: php, ubuntu, pcntl

I'm about to start working with yii framework using composer and for that I need this php pcntl module working. As I read from the manuals it is not installed in ubuntu by default.
Because of that I've found some instructions something like this

```
mkdir php
cd php
apt-get source php5
cd php5-(WHATEVER_RELEASE)/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make

Then:
cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php5/WHEVER_YOUR_SO_FILES_ARE/
echo "extension=pcntl.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/pcntl.ini
```

and made installation.
But know I'm getting message

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

which probably means that maybe this module was already in my system.
So what are my steps now ? Just pay no attention to this warning or I must do something to fix this problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP warning : Module 'mcrypt' already loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923534/php-warning-module-mcrypt-already-loaded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your php.ini contains two or more of these lines:

```
extension=pcntl.so
```

Remove all except one.

`php.ini` usually lives in `/etc/php.ini or /etc/php5/php.in`i. Sometimes additional `.ini` files are included, you can see all of them with:

```
[~]% php -i | grep \.ini\$
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php.ini
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
```

Comment: In my case it was a duplication from: /etc/php.d/pcntl.ini

Comment: Your grep statement would potentially miss some loaded modules. Try using `php -i | grep .ini` instead.